# Inserting html in div with JQuery removes Anchor tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to do something that should be very simple yet my head is about to explode considering I cannot get it to work.

In my asp.net MVC app, I make an Ajax call to the server, and the server sends back a message (as a string), which includes a link.

The message basically looks like this : `Action failed, <a href="">Learn more.</a>`.
I am inserting this returned message in a div that shows the alerts from the server.

However, whatever I try, the '`<a href="">Learn more.</a>`' part will never be inserted. 
If I do `alert(returnedMessage)`, it shows the correct html, but as soon as I do 
`$(mydiv).html(returnedMessage)`, the anchor-tag is gone. I tried unescaping, normal jscript innerHtml...not sure what I'm missing.

Thanks!

**UPDATE with some extra code **
I have the ajax call that returns a message. I have a method that then sets the message into the div and shows the alert.

the ajax call handling:

```
  success: function (result) {      
                    if (result.Message) {
                       showAlert(result.Message);
                    }
            },
```

The javascript:

```
  function showAlert(message) {
  // neither setting the actual div, nor the span works
      alert(message);
        $('#server-message').html(message)
        //$('#server-message span').html(message);
        $('#server-message').fadeIn(100);
    };
```

the html:

```
<div id="server-message">
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try with `$(myDiv).html(returnedMessage)`or maybe append it inside the `div`? Also, some code snipet would be nice ;)

Comment: $(mydiv).append($(returnMessage));

Comment: How are you 'inserting' it?

Comment: I tried both append, and .html(message) and neither work :(

Comment: @DeeMac $(mydiv).html(returnedMessage), or normal jscript setting the innerHtml

Comment: Please, @NeedACar provide us some code. Also, what's the output for `returnedMessage.toString()`?

Comment: I added the actual method that is supposed to set the alert.

Comment: @Bursos if I do 'alert(message.tostring())' it shows the html WITH a href-tag, but if I set the html in the div, the anchor-tag is gone again.

Comment: Have my upvote, it has me stumped to be honest. Not a clue. I'd suggest setting `innerHtml` but you've apparently tried that.

Comment: @NeedACar if you try to insert it on the `body`what's happend? ie: `$('body').html(message)'. Maybe you have other Javascript modifying those DOM elements. Also you can check the DOM changes by set up a breakpoint on the HTML inspector (Chrome for the sure, others browsers idk).

Comment: @Bursos $('body').html(message); results in the same issue, it shows only the text without the 'learn more'-ahref at the end -> <body>Action failed, </body>

Comment: also worth trying if you are escaping th double quotes properly :) var returnMessage = '<a href=\"\">Learn more.</a>';

Comment: When you say 'show' - you are checking the DOM via dev tools or something aren't you? I'd hope you're not just relying on whether you can see it in the browser or not. If it's styled in a way that would make it not visible, that would explain why only your string appears and not your `anchor` tag.

Comment: @DeeMac yes I'm checking in Chrome f12 if the html actually appears.

Comment: Make a jsfiddle please.

Comment: Oke the problem is solved thanks to @vidriduch, in the backend, where I obviously have the message as a string, I did not escape the quotes with a slash, but I used the @ symbol, which works in C#, but apparently not for this usage in the frontend. If you make it an answer I can set it to Answered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

also worth trying if you are escaping the double quotes properly :)

```
var returnMessage = '<a href=\"\">Learn more.</a>';
```

Comment: quoted from question: Oke the problem is solved thanks to @vidriduch, in the backend, where I obviously have the message as a string, I did not escape the quotes with a slash, but I used the @ symbol, which works in C#, but apparently not for this usage in the frontend. If you make it an answer I can set it to Answered :)

Answer (score -1):

You should your message to `.html()` function `$(mydiv).html(returnedMessage)` if you doing `$(mydiv).html =` you only overwriting `html` property in this object.

Comment: I used that, I wrote it wrong in my question, correct my question, thanks but that was was not the problem